# Difference between pre-configured web servers versus building your own

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web, server

What are the ***pros and cons*** of building your *own* web server, and the difference between building your own versus installing a '*pre-configured*' web servers (such as: LAMP, WAMP, XAMPP, and other else). Is there any good benifits of building your own web server?

If you're gonna have your own server, would you rather build it on your own, or just download one from the internet? and Why?

Comment: Try to build one and let us know your thoughts first!

Comment: All depends on how your "web server" should be used.  Add more info about it.

Comment: The fact that you are asking here suggests that you might want to use existing components instead of writing your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building your own web-server

Pros:

- It will work exactly according to your taste
- It will use the technologies of your choice
- At the end you will know virtually everything about it, while with other webservers sometimes that is not possible
- You will be famous if you implement something fantastic

Cons:

- You will have to do a lot of complicated stuff which will delay the start of the task you wanted to work on in the first place
- You on your own will not be capable to be even close to other webservers, developed by many programmers. You are one, they are legion
- As times are changing, modern techniques will pour up and you will need to do a lot of work to adapt to the changes
- Other webservers are free in many cases, while developing your webserver is very expensive: you pay with your sweat and tears

But the most important point is that before you start implementing your webserver try out others. Even if you reach to the conclusion that you want to write your own your experience with other webservers will help you a lot in planning yours.

Comment: I wonder about the problems with this answer so I can improve any shortcomings.